# Wifi stops after some time in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. When I start my OS and connect with WiFi and I am surfing the net, after some time – approx. after 2 hours – the WiFi stops.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: We cannot help you if we don't know your wireless hardware.

Comment: What does `grep wlan /var/log/kern.log` show at the time of the failure?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Realtek Wifi because it causes problem with new kernel.

You need to install backported modules from the 3.19 kernel (happened to me too)
Here's the code on how to

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
cd backports-3.19-rc1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

HOPE IT WORKS :D

Comment: And why Realtek?